# fetchxml with group by return page cookies ="" and more recored =false

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, fetchxml

when try to do paging with fetchxml with group by 
always pagecookies return empty string and more records retuen false

```
 string fetchXml = @" 
        <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false' aggregate='true'> 
            <entity name='appointment'> 
            <all-attributes />
               <attribute name='shiftstart' alias='shiftstartyear' groupby='true'  dategrouping='year' /> 
               <attribute name='shiftstart' alias='shiftstartmonth' groupby='true'  dategrouping='month' /> 
               <attribute name='shiftstart' alias='shiftstartday' groupby='true'  dategrouping='day' /> 
               <attribute name='contId' alias='contId' groupby='true' /> 
                  <filter type='and'>
                    <condition attribute ='status' operator='not-in'><value>2</value><value>3</value>
                    </condition>
                        <condition attribute ='contact' operator='eq' value ='" + contactId + @"' />
                    </filter>


                </entity> 
        </fetch>";
        string xml = CreateXml(fetchXml, PageCookies, pagenumber, pageSize);

        // Excute the fetch query and get the xml result.
        RetrieveMultipleRequest fetchRequest1 = new RetrieveMultipleRequest
        {
            Query = new FetchExpression(xml)
        };

        var returnCollection = ((RetrieveMultipleResponse)GlobalCode.Service.Execute(fetchRequest1)).EntityCollection;
```

Comment: Is this question incomplete? I can't see where you're using `PageCookies`, `pagenumber` or `pageSize`

Comment: string xml = CreateXml(fetchXml, PageCookies, pagenumber, pageSize);

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit over max result aggregate query can return (50000).

> Ref:
>   [Fetch XML report aggregate undocumented limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783871/fetch-xml-report-aggregate-undocumented-limit)

So paging over aggregated queries doesn't make much sense - i.e. before paging is taken into an account you're query will be trimmed to 50k results.